# How do I send an HTML response with mod_wsgi? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, html, response, wsgi

Here's my sample app:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b"""
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>It works!</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    """

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

When I run it, I get:

[image]

As you can see, the html is completely ignored and treated as pure text. I'm a complete beginner with mod_wsgi, so...

How can I deal with requests and responses **natively**? I'm using this word because when I google "wsgi response object", I get [Werkzeug](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwiJ4v3j8qrIAhXJF5AKHVKOD8A&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwerkzeug.pocoo.org%2Fdocs%2F0.10%2Fwrappers%2F&usg=AFQjCNG4Rc2K8kYA8EE8o4mhJO55L5_2DQ&sig2=lwwsm3VHozp70yvzMrayBg) and [WebOb](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjACahUKEwiJ4v3j8qrIAhXJF5AKHVKOD8A&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebob.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNGie3mKMBrZpsA1xwzZenwWdAxDbQ&sig2=JtYbkR8506O7nLgaE6RBHw) for example, or random Django-related stuff. I want **pure python** / native material. So,

Ho do I send an HTML response with mod_wsgi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with mod_wsgi.

For some reason you've explicitly set the content type header to be "text/plain", so the browser will interpret it as, well, text. Don't do that: it should be "text/html".

Note, you really shouldn't reject the frameworks. Writing applications in pure wsgi is *possible*, but unnecessarily complex; a framework simply abstracts away that complexity.